# How to initialise the set function of useState for TypeScript in a createContext?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, use-state

I have a `Provider` that provides a state variable and its corresponding setter through two `contexts`.

```
const BookedBatchContext = createContext({})
const SetBookedBatchContext = createContext(null)

const initialState = {
  id: null
}
```

The `Provider` looks like this:

```
export const BookedBatchProvider = ({ children }: { children: any }) => {
  const [bookedBatch, setBookedBatch] = useState(localState ||initialState)

  return (
    <SetBookedBatchContext.Provider value={setBookedBatch}>
      <BookedBatchContext.Provider value={bookedBatch}>
        { children }
      </BookedBatchContext.Provider>
    </SetBookedBatchContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

Through a custom hook I make the `setBookedBatch` available to other components:

```
export const useBookedBatch = () => {
  const bookedBatch = useContext(BookedBatchContext)
  const setBookedBatch = useContext(SetBookedBatchContext)

  return { bookedBatch, setBookedBatch }
}
```

When trying to use the `setBookedBatch` function, I get following error in a given component:

```
setBookedBatch(selectedBatch)
```

The error:

```
TS2721: Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'null'.
```

Since the setter of the `useState` function is a function that I didn't create, I don't know how to initialise it when I create the context:

```
const SetBookedBatchContext = createContext(null)
```

So that TypeScript does not complain.

1. How can I know the initial value of the setter function?
2. How can I avoid that TS complains about the null value, if I am not providing any types?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The return types of `React.createContext` and `React.useState` are determined by inference from the *initial values* you pass in.

1.) You can create the proper context type by manually specifying the generic type:

```
const SetBookedBatchContext = createContext<null | React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<State>>>(null)
```

Note: The setter for `useState` has type `React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<State>>`, where `State` is whatever `localState || initialState` is.

2.) Assert in your custom Hook `useBookedBatch`, that `setBookedBatch` is *not* `null`:

```
export const useBookedBatch = () => {
  const bookedBatch = useContext(BookedBatchContext)
  const setBookedBatch = useContext(SetBookedBatchContext)
  if (setBookedBatch === null) throw new Error() // this will make setBookedBatch non-null
  return { bookedBatch, setBookedBatch }
  // returns: { bookedBatch: {}; setBookedBatch: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<State>>; }
}
```

3.) Then `setBookedBatch` can be invoked without assertion later on:

```
const App = () => {
  const { setBookedBatch } = useBookedBatch()
  useEffect(() => { setBookedBatch({ id: "foo" }) }, [])
}
```

[Sample on the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDec1SoxIDCEAdsQB5ZwCuAzkgMowrHaOkXW1cCiAM0FIMcAL5xBUCCDgAiQuhjyAsACgNaCg3gAhCBADWSACZ72aABZlKSGnAC8%20JcVu8AFDnEBKLTvhmJBgDYzMLGGt3e3hnAiJuOxoAHnI6ABt0uAAfRFQMADoAEWAGMEsrZORlAqCYVnYkAEEMYApkhuIAPh6PNMy-TXUYAE8wJDhOiec8YFMALjhdKGByAHMcuH6s8X9yXThV4BhgFHSpxamnXEOFrYydvYP0iDQzi8m2Ymujk-evpAaDT2SCwfABOChEzmCoABRkADc5kgoNcvPgrMB0qZCOQJIs8NYsTikORFihyCMJD4nF1cBo4OD9vAANoAI0M0Ii1mwTBCnPCFQAutcuFMPC83ucATlcr9TtLGoMGXBCDA6FA8R4VYyOsEoYLIjYeDECvCIEjTCi4AiznQkI4cHyDTCjeIujrGXBki7ucakjAzYjkajbel7Y6OWFXdZ3Z6vbgidjcbt1AndQB6X0VaI0IMWkMetNe5IZurZo25wPmy0oouMwap4FUUHwbTM%20hMCvWNE0xx0nAq9sHKNciqiphVjzd-28QaM4fwZ0CmNWCeJTzlld%20qvzw6COAeZfRv1ORzObY0mBWGQAdy2SHv-CgMigHj3ao1eLwo8NPKW%20rbuOkgZhmAH8ieFSLNUhQlGUFRVPkgZ1FMLQnO0Uw9BoTbqIucBNGAYC9rS9LFnheDHmORoSOuM7viqAjCKIMAeO%20JEUYBkFGuicyLPIgiGPI1ISNgLJCo2QA)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you please point me to the documentation where I can find the types for React.dispatch? (createContext<null | React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<State>>>(null))

Comment: I can't find it, I always end up in redux documentation

Comment: You can find types for [`useState`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/2034c45/types/react/index.d.ts#L879) and [`React.Dispatch`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/2034c45/types/react/index.d.ts#L836-L841) on DefinitelyTyped `@types/react`