# How to pass a type down to a React Context Consumer in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings

I want to create a React Context and pass `state` and `setState` properties `useState` Hook down to a Consumer.

I have a `Step` and a `Context` types:

```
type Step = {
  step: string;
};

type Context = {
  step: Step;
  setStep: Dispatch<SetStateAction<Step>>;
};
```

I create a context:

```
export const StepContext = createContext<Context | undefined>(undefined);
```

I create a `StepProvider` and a hook:

```
const StepProvider = ({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) => {
  const [step, setStep] = useState<Step>({ step: 'one' });
  return <StepContext.Provider value={{ step, setStep }}>{children}</StepContext.Provider>;
};
```

I create a `StepConsumer`:

```
const StepConsumer = () => {
  const { step, setStep } = useContext(StepContext);
  return <div>{...}</div>;
};
```

But in:

```
const { step } = useContext(StepContext)
```

`step` and `setStep` return the following error `TS2339: Property 'step' does not exist on type 'Context | undefined'`

[image]

Am I not passing the types the right way?

Thanks

Comment: The context type is determined by the initial value. To exclude `undefined`, you can encapsulate your context in a custom hook, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60713501/5669456).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to initialise the set function of useState for TypeScript in a createContext?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60712598/how-to-initialise-the-set-function-of-usestate-for-typescript-in-a-createcontext)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're syntax is correct but usage of the context is not thorough enough to ensure the value is not `undefined` when deconstructing.

The error itself is checked by the `strictNullChecks` compiler option, your code will work in it's current state if `strictNullChecks: false` is set in your tsconfig.

However, to keep that option enabled you'll need to make sure the context value is not `undefined` before deconstructing or using the `StepContext` values, Typescript won't let you access it without checking first.

If you change the deconstruction to a simple assignment and then check the context is not `undefined` the error will go away.

```js
const stepContext = React.useContext(StepContext);

if (typeof stepContext !== "undefined") {
  stepContext.setStep("foo")
}

// simplified
if (stepContext) {
  stepContext.setStep("foo")
}

// simplified further
stepContext?.setStep("foo");
```

Additionally, with `strictNullChecks: false` you're also able to define the context type without the `undefined` type value.

```js
export const StepContext = createContext<Context>(undefined);
```